# How can I change the alert sound on Windows Phone 8.1 update?

Tags: lumia, 8.1, settings, lumia-520, alert

My Nokia Lumia 520 running Windows Phone 8.1 Update produces a system alert sound whenever I complete a call (because I am on a *pay as you go* plan - the alert text indicates the cost of the call). The alert produces a sound that is the same as the sound named "Nokia message." Unchecking "System alerts" in Settings -> ringtones + sounds does not prevent the alert sound. Changing the sound set in Settings -> notifications + actions -> Phone has no effect on this particular message. I haven't been able to find what setting to use to change the sound played for these alerts.

How can I silence or change the alert (or message?) sound?

(The alert/message is not a text message - a record of it does not appear in the Messaging app.)
(Carrier is Airvoice Wireless MVNO on AT&T network.)

Comment: You say the alert is from a text? If so, you should be able to add the sender to your contacts and assign it a custom text alert tone.

Comment: @Indrek No, it is not a text message.  It is a full screen message (like the phone equivalent of a windows MessageBox?).  A record of it does not appear in the Messaging app.  Changing the sound at Settings | notifications + actions | Phone has no effect on this alert/message.

Comment: Unless someone corrects me on this, I'm guessing that the message is being pushed by your carrier, so there's no way to change it.

Comment: @Drowin I don't doubt that the message is being pushed by the carrier but I don't think the sound is pushed by them with the message text.

Comment: @seane Whenever I get a message that isn't sent by the OS, the Nokia Message sound is the sound it makes. So I think that it is a preset sound that the OS uses when it doesn't know what the message is, specifically. Which would make sense, since it's a Nokia phone, and it's a message... (Nokia + message = Nokia message). Again, if someone knows differently, please correct me.

Comment: @Drowin That does make sense.  I'll post a different question to see if we can change the waveform associated with 'Nokia Message'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no way to turn off **USSD** tones.

Comment: thanks - I wasn't aware of USSD.  For others: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_Supplementary_Service_Data

Answer (score 0):

Try if this will work:

- Choose the Ringtones+Sounds option in your Settings
- Scroll down to the bottom of the Ringtone+Sounds page until you find the “Manage App Sounds” button bar.
- You will see options to choose your Quick Action button and just below is a listing of apps that support custom alert sounds.
- Tap "Store"
- Set Notification sound
- - *None* to be silent

[Source](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-custom-alerts-windows-phone-81)

Comment: Nice try, but I already have Store set to None. :(