# Is there a way to change the "Nokia message" sound/waveform on Nokia Lumia phones?

Tags: lumia, lumia-520, sound

On the Nokia Lumia 520 with Windows Phone 8.1 Update, it appears that the "Nokia message" sound is the default alert sound used for [USSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_Supplementary_Service_Data) messages (see [How can I change the alert sound on Windows Phone 8.1 update?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8681/how-can-i-change-the-alert-sound-on-windows-phone-8-1-update)).

Is there a way to change the wavefile/source audio of the "Nokia message" sound (for example, through Visual Studio or Windows Phone 8 SDK)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is not possible to access the Windows Phone OS notification sounds the "Nokia message" sound can not be replaced. This is not possible through the Windows Phone SDK / Visual Studio as these tools don't give you any special access to the Phone OS files. There's also no API that I'm aware of that you could use to programmatically change the sound, sorry.